# Apache POI multiple column labels in pivot

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

I am wanting to create a pivot table in excel with apache poi. That part itself works fine and I get the table like I want it to be. Now I want to add a second `Column Label` to break down the data even further, but I can't seem to add the second column properly.

My current (working) code for just one column:

```
private void createPivotTotalOverview(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFSheet data = workBook.getSheet("Total Cost Table");

    CellReference c1 = new CellReference(0, 0);
    CellReference c2 = new CellReference(data.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1, data.getRow(0).getLastCellNum() - 1);

    AreaReference ar = new AreaReference(c1, c2);
    CellReference cr = new CellReference(CellAddress.A1.formatAsString());

    XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(ar, cr, data);   

    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(9).setAxis(STAxis.AXIS_COL);
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(9).addNewItems();
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(9).getItems().addNewItem()
            .setT(STItemType.DEFAULT);

    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields().addNewField().setX(9);

    pivotTable.addRowLabel(10);
    pivotTable.addRowLabel(11);
    pivotTable.addRowLabel(2);
    pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 8);
}
```

And I tried to add a second column like this:

```
private void createPivotTotalOverview(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFSheet data = workBook.getSheet("Total Cost Table");

    CellReference c1 = new CellReference(0, 0);
    CellReference c2 = new CellReference(data.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1, data.getRow(0).getLastCellNum() - 1);

    AreaReference ar = new AreaReference(c1, c2);
    CellReference cr = new CellReference(CellAddress.A1.formatAsString());

    XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(ar, cr, data);   

    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(9).setAxis(STAxis.AXIS_COL);
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(9).addNewItems();
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(9).getItems().addNewItem()
            .setT(STItemType.DEFAULT);
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(12).setAxis(STAxis.AXIS_COL);
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(12).addNewItems();
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(12).getItems().addNewItem()
            .setT(STItemType.DATA);

    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields().addNewField().setX(9);
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields().addNewField().setX(12);
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields().setCount(2);


    pivotTable.addRowLabel(10);
    pivotTable.addRowLabel(11);
    pivotTable.addRowLabel(2);
    pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 8);
}
```

but with the second code the pivot table seems to break as I can open the excel, but it doesn't display that table anymore. Excel asks me if I want to recover as much data as possible and then it tells me that `Removed Part: /xl/pivotTables/pivotTable3.xml part with XML error.  (PivotTable view) Load error. Line 2, column 0.`

Can anyone help me to add a second column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `colFields` element in `xl/pivotTables/pivotTable1.xml` should look like this

```
<colFields count="2">
 <field x="9"/>
 <field x="12"/>
</colFields>
```

for multiple col fields. But your code adds two `colFields` elements which leads to this:

```
<colFields count="2">
 <field x="9"/>
</colFields>
<colFields>
 <field x="12"/>
</colFields>
```

which is wrong.

So instead of

```
---
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields().addNewField().setX(9);
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields().addNewField().setX(12);
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields().setCount(2);
...
```

do

```
...
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields().addNewField().setX(9);
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields().addNewField().setX(12);
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields().setCount(2);
...
```

And please do not overstraining the tolerance of Excel. Why using `.setT(STItemType.DATA)` as item type for second col field? Why not also `.setT(STItemType.DEFAULT)` as in the first? The type `DATA` leads Excel 2007 to crash. Excel 365 seems tolerating this.

So please use:

```
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(12).getItems().addNewItem()
   .setT(STItemType.DEFAULT);
```

And btw.:

Constructor `AreaReference(CellReference topLeft, CellReference botRight)` is deprecated. Do using `AreaReference(CellReference topLeft, CellReference botRight, SpreadsheetVersion version)` instead.

Comment: This works fine, thank you very much. The `STItemType.DATA` was just a test by myself to see if it solves my problem and as I am still running poi 3.15, `AreaReference` only has the constructor I use as non-deprecated, but still thanks for the hints